# Bootstrap 3 <div class="col-md-6" not rendering in website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i was making a registration form but there is a problem.

```
<div class="container padding-top-10">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Registeration
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form>
                <label for="firstName" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label for"address1" class="control-label">Address:</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address1" placeholder="Address line 1" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2" placeholder="Address line 2" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, it renders like this:
[how the image renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU0Qn.png)

While i want the length text input of the frist name and last name longer so that each of takes equal amount of space. And the address text input taking the whole page stacked on one another.

But it wasn't rendering what i wanted to be.
Please help me!!!

Comment: Please provide a fiddle demo.

Comment: Nesting `.col-md-12` inside of `.row` is redundant. `.form-control` provides `width: 100%; and display: block;` so you could really just remove those elements entirely, or replace them with a single `<div>` if you'd prefer.

Comment: It looks like https://jsfiddle.net/n0LuLwad/. What other thing you use in your code?

Comment: @Jacob Gee: http://www.bootply.com/DagviJWthI. It looks like this. what issue do you have?